# Can't install xorg-init on arch

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, pacman

I am not able to install `xorg-init` on a new arch install. It is possible to install other packages, but not that one. I updated the database with `pacman -Syy`, but it still won't work. Error message:

```
$ pacman -S xorg-init
error: target not found: xorg-init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [there is no package by that name](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=xorg-init&maintainer=&flagged=).

What are you trying to do? Are you following one of the official guides?

Comment: Ok, nevermind... Confused it with `xorg-xinit`, sorry! Although you helped anyway